# Locate a element in selenium modal pop up python

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

I really don't know how I can locate the inner elements of this modal pop up, normally I would just highlight something in de popup and copy the xpath, but now whenever I click inspect the modal pop closes itself and I cant see the structure. I already tried adding forced states in the google inspect tool but that didn't work. I dont have a url since its in a private session(feel free to make a free account on pipedrive) but here is the inspect code when hovering/clicking on the search element: [image]

And here is the code without hovering:
[image]

Please let me know what I can do.

Comment: Can you post the URL and mention how to navigate to that specific page?

Comment: @AbiSaran the url is user specific, but i managed to get the right xpath by using break on subtree modifications, just need to find a way now to manage the detection.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the right xpath by using break on subtree modifications on the top div of the structure, this way you can enable the modal, and see and navigate to the structure. [image]